# How to align fields in GridbagLayout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I need to align the time so that it would look like this: [image]

And so far I have achieve it in this code: (This is a short ver. of my code)

```
package cardlayoutalignment;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class gridbaglayoutdemo {

    JFrame Card = new JFrame();

FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,2,2);
Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray);
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);

public static GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
final static boolean shouldFill = true;

JPanel container = new JPanel();
JPanel divider = new JPanel();
JPanel bodypanel = new JPanel();
final JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

public gridbaglayoutdemo(){
        Card.setVisible(true);
    Card.setSize(605,333);
    Card.setTitle("Tank Delivery");
    //Card.setResizable(false);

    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
    int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth())/2);
    int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight())/2);

    Card.setLocation(x, y);
    Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


    bodypanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    divider.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    container.setLayout(cl);
    cl.show(container, "1");


    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Memory is full. Finish 1 transaction in order to use Memory again");


    panel_1.setLayout(grid);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Enter Tank:");
    label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_1.add(label_1, c);

    JComboBox box_1 = new JComboBox();
    box_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 20;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_1.add(box_1,c);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 30;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panel_1.add(label, c);


    panel_4.setLayout(grid);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Enter Date:");
    label_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_4.add(label_2,c);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    df.setLenient(false);

    JFormattedTextField text_2 = new JFormattedTextField(df);
    text_2.setValue(new Date());
    text_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_4.add(text_2,c);

    JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Enter Date:");
    label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 10;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
    panel_4.add(label_3,c);

    JLabel text_3 = new JLabel("");
    text_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 15;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(text_3,c);

    String time3 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(new java.util.Date() );
    JFormattedTextField text_33 = new JFormattedTextField();
    text_33.setValue(time3);
    //text_33.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 15;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(text_33,c);

    JLabel label_4 = new JLabel(":");
    label_4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 15;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(label_4,c);

    String time2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(new java.util.Date() );
    JFormattedTextField text_4 = new JFormattedTextField();
    text_4.setValue(time2);
    //text_4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridy = 15;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(text_4,c);

    JButton btnup = new JButton("UP");
    btnup.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 10;
    c.gridy = 15;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(btnup, c);

    JButton btndown = new JButton("DOWN");
    btndown.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 10;
    c.gridy = 20;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(btndown, c);


    JLabel label14 = new JLabel("");
    label14.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 30;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panel_4.add(label14, c);


    buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0));

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("< Back");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        cl.previous(container);
        buttonpanel.repaint();
        }   
    });
    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnBack.setFocusable(false);
    btnBack.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    btnBack.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnBack.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    btnBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
    btnBack.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    buttonpanel.add(btnBack);

    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next >");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cl.next(container);
            buttonpanel.repaint();
        }   
    });
    btnNext.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnNext.setFocusable(false);
    btnNext.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    btnNext.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnNext.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    btnNext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
    btnNext.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    buttonpanel.add(btnNext);

    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnCancel.setFocusable(false);
    btnCancel.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnCancel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    btnCancel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
    btnCancel.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    buttonpanel.add(btnCancel);



    divider.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);     
        container.add(panel_1, "1");
        //container.add(p2.panel_2, "2");
        //container.add(p3.panel_3, "3");
        container.add(panel_4, "4");
    divider.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    JPanel numberpanel = new JPanel();
    numberpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(221,0));
    numberpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,0,0,10));
    numberpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray));
    numberpanel.setLayout(flow);

    JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
    button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_7.setFocusable(false);
    button_7.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_7.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_7.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_7.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_7);

    JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
    button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_8.setFocusable(false);
    button_8.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_8.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_8.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_8.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_8);

    JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
    button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_9.setFocusable(false);
    button_9.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_9.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_9.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_9.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_9);

    JButton button_4 = new JButton("4");
    button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_4.setFocusable(false);
    button_4.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_4.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_4.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_4.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_4);

    JButton button_5 = new JButton("5");
    button_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_5.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_5.setFocusable(false);
    button_5.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_5.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_5.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_5.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_5);

    JButton button_6 = new JButton("6");
    button_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_6.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_6.setFocusable(false);
    button_6.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_6.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_6.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_6.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_6);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("1");
    button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_1.setFocusable(false);
    button_1.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_1.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_1.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_1.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_1);

    JButton button_2 = new JButton("2");
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_2.setFocusable(false);
    button_2.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_2.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_2.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_2.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_2);

    JButton button_3 = new JButton("3");
    button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_3.setFocusable(false);
    button_3.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_3.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_3.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_3.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_3);

    JButton button_0 = new JButton("0");
    button_0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_0.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_0.setFocusable(false);
    button_0.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_0.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_0.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_0.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_0);

    JButton button_left = new JButton("");
    button_left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_left.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\left.png"));
    button_left.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_left.setFocusable(false);
    button_left.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_left.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_left.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_left.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_left);

    JButton button_right = new JButton("");
    button_right.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_right.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\right.png"));
    button_right.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_right.setFocusable(false);
    button_right.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_right.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_right.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_right.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_right);


    Card.add(bodypanel);
    bodypanel.add(divider, BorderLayout.WEST);
    bodypanel.add(numberpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);



}

   public static void main(String[] args){
     //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
 {
    @Override
     public void run()
     {
     new gridbaglayoutdemo();         
     }
     });

     }
 }
```

My problem is that Below the label of the "Enter Time:" I put a blank label there. When I put the `JTextField` there I can't align it just like the picture above because the cell of it is being aligned with the `JLabel` above it. I have tried the `gridwidth`, `gridheight`(- for the up and down button), `weightx`, `insets`, and adding a blank `JLabel`(- to occupy the space at the end of the line). And all of that failed. I don't know what I did wrong or anything. I also know that I don't have to call `setPreferredSize` but I have to because I want the time field to get the same width just like the picture above. I don't think that the alignment of up and down button will be just like in the picture because in `GridBagLayout` there's no in between. Well I have tried to set the `gridheight` of the time field to 2 and still the result is like that. Is there a way to align those fields just like in the picture?

Comment: *"(This is a short ver. of my code)"*  Short?  At 489 LOC, you have an interesting definition of 'short'.

Comment: `c.gridy = 30;` Why are you using such numbers? Also try to organize better your code, your GUI has a clear structure, 2 cards, a num panel... so put all of that in different methods. It will make your life easier.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes. I'm sorry if it is not so short. xD

Comment: @DSquare well its the position of the field. I skip by 10 or 5. There's no problem with the cards and the numpanel because in my code its all in separate classes. Also my original code is organized. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not aware that a GridBagLayout works with a Grid NxM which means that all components in the same column have cells of the same width, and all components in the same row reside in cells of the same height. It's just a grid.

The problem is very simple, you have some components in the column 0: the "Enter Date:" Label, the input date TextField... so the widthest component determines how big is that column. Now you want to put a bunch of text fields, labels and buttons representing the [14:00 Up/down]. The way you are doing it now is first putting an empty label that doesn't really do anything (other than use its cell) and then putting said components in columns 2, 3, 4...

However as I said the column 0 is very width so the column 1+ starts at the right of everything that is already put there, so that's why all those components appear "on the right",  because the column 0 is very width.

Now to put them in the proper position there are 2 options. Either make all those components above span through several columns so you can then use those columns to put everythting you need under those components or create a panel with the components and then put this panel in the column 0 under "Enter Time:"

In my opinion the second aproach is way better so I went and defined a `timeInputPanel` filled it with the components we want and then put it in the column 0 of the `panel_4`. Now because the `timeInputPanel` is just 1 component it can reside without any problems inside the  column 0 even if it contains several other components.

The relevant code is just this:

```
JPanel timeInputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
timeInputPanel.add(text_33);
timeInputPanel.add(label_4);
timeInputPanel.add(text_4);
timeInputPanel.add(upDownPanel);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 15;
c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
panel_4.add(timeInputPanel, c);
```

Of course you might want to change the GridBagConstraints to your liking, the only thing important is `c.gridx = 0;` and a proper `gridy`.

It looks like this:

[image]

Full code:

```
package cardlayoutalignment;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class gridbaglayoutdemo
{

    JFrame Card = new JFrame();

    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 2, 2);
    Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white, Color.gray);
    Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);

    public static GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    JPanel divider = new JPanel();
    JPanel bodypanel = new JPanel();
    final JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public gridbaglayoutdemo()
    {
        Card.setVisible(true);
        Card.setSize(605, 333);
        Card.setTitle("Tank Delivery");
        // Card.setResizable(false);

        final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight()) / 2);

        Card.setLocation(x, y);
        Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        bodypanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        divider.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        container.setLayout(cl);
        cl.show(container, "1");

        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        // "Memory is full. Finish 1 transaction in order to use Memory again");

        panel_1.setLayout(grid);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Enter Tank:");
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        panel_1.add(label_1, c);

        JComboBox box_1 = new JComboBox();
        box_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 20;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        panel_1.add(box_1, c);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 30;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
        panel_1.add(label, c);

        panel_4.setLayout(grid);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Enter Date:");
        label_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        panel_4.add(label_2, c);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        df.setLenient(false);

        JFormattedTextField text_2 = new JFormattedTextField(df);
        text_2.setValue(new Date());
        text_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        panel_4.add(text_2, c);

        JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Enter Time:");
        label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 10;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        panel_4.add(label_3, c);


        String time3 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(new java.util.Date());
        JFormattedTextField text_33 = new JFormattedTextField();
        text_33.setValue(time3);

        JLabel label_4 = new JLabel(":");
        label_4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        String time2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(new java.util.Date());
        JFormattedTextField text_4 = new JFormattedTextField();
        text_4.setValue(time2);

        JButton btnup = new JButton("UP");
        btnup.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        JButton btndown = new JButton("DOWN");
        btndown.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        JPanel upDownPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        upDownPanel.add(btnup, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        upDownPanel.add(btndown, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JPanel timeInputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        timeInputPanel.add(text_33);
        timeInputPanel.add(label_4);
        timeInputPanel.add(text_4);
        timeInputPanel.add(upDownPanel);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 15;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
        panel_4.add(timeInputPanel, c);

        JLabel label14 = new JLabel("");
        label14.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 30;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
        panel_4.add(label14, c);

        buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0));

        JButton btnBack = new JButton("< Back");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                cl.previous(container);
                buttonpanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        btnBack.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnBack.setFocusable(false);
        btnBack.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        btnBack.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnBack.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        btnBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
        btnBack.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        buttonpanel.add(btnBack);

        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next >");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                cl.next(container);
                buttonpanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        btnNext.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnNext.setFocusable(false);
        btnNext.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        btnNext.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnNext.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        btnNext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
        btnNext.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        buttonpanel.add(btnNext);

        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnCancel.setFocusable(false);
        btnCancel.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnCancel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        btnCancel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
        btnCancel.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        buttonpanel.add(btnCancel);

        divider.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(panel_1, "1");
        // container.add(p2.panel_2, "2");
        // container.add(p3.panel_3, "3");
        container.add(panel_4, "4");
        divider.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel numberpanel = new JPanel();
        numberpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(221, 0));
        numberpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 10));
        numberpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white, Color.gray));
        numberpanel.setLayout(flow);

        JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
        button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_7.setFocusable(false);
        button_7.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_7.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_7.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_7.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_7);

        JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
        button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_8.setFocusable(false);
        button_8.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_8.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_8.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_8.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_8);

        JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
        button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_9.setFocusable(false);
        button_9.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_9.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_9.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_9.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_9);

        JButton button_4 = new JButton("4");
        button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_4.setFocusable(false);
        button_4.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_4.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_4.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_4.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_4);

        JButton button_5 = new JButton("5");
        button_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_5.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_5.setFocusable(false);
        button_5.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_5.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_5.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_5.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_5);

        JButton button_6 = new JButton("6");
        button_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_6.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_6.setFocusable(false);
        button_6.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_6.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_6.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_6.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_6);

        JButton button_1 = new JButton("1");
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_1.setFocusable(false);
        button_1.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_1.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_1.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_1.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_1);

        JButton button_2 = new JButton("2");
        button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_2.setFocusable(false);
        button_2.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_2.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_2.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_2.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_2);

        JButton button_3 = new JButton("3");
        button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_3.setFocusable(false);
        button_3.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_3.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_3.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_3.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_3);

        JButton button_0 = new JButton("0");
        button_0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_0.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_0.setFocusable(false);
        button_0.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_0.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_0.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_0.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_0);

        JButton button_left = new JButton("");
        button_left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_left.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\left.png"));
        button_left.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_left.setFocusable(false);
        button_left.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_left.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_left.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_left.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_left);

        JButton button_right = new JButton("");
        button_right.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        });
        button_right.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\right.png"));
        button_right.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        button_right.setFocusable(false);
        button_right.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        button_right.setFocusPainted(false);
        button_right.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
        button_right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
        button_right.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        numberpanel.add(button_right);

        Card.add(bodypanel);
        bodypanel.add(divider, BorderLayout.WEST);
        bodypanel.add(numberpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new gridbaglayoutdemo();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you very much! Now I've learned something. I actually know that a column will have the same width and height but the only thing I didn't know is that I can put my other fields in a panel and I can insert it in just a cell. I'll change my `gridy` by 1 only. I got used entering values skipping 10s or 5s. I'm sorry for that.